# Find when value repeats in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a data frame of temperatures (`Temp`) with two columns:

- Time
- Temperature

And I have another data frame (`Activated`) with a single column that describes times when some equipment activated:

- Time

Both of these data frames are over the same period, and each "TimeStamp" exist in both.

I want to know, for each time in the `Activated` data frame how long it passed till the temperature risen.

I know how to do it "C style", with two for loops (one iterates over `Activated` finds the time in `Temp` and then loops forward till finds higher temperature).

But I'm sure there is a much better cleaner and efficient way using pandas. Example data:

`Temp`

```
1 25.6
2 25.4
3 24
4 25.8
5 23.2
6 24.3
7 28.1
```

`Activated`

```
2
4
```

For the first row in `Activated` the time is `2` - the temperature in time `2` was `25.4`, the result should be `2` because only on time `4` it risen.
For the second row in `Activated` the time is `4` - the temperature in time `4` was `25.8`, the result should be `3` because only on time `7` it risen.

output for `2` is 2 and for `4` is 3

Comment: Is your base temp 25 ? and I suppose the data is every second ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal not sure I understand your question. I don't have base temp.

Comment: "how long it passed till the temperature risen."-- risen from what...what is the base ?

Comment: from the temperature that was in the timestamp mentioned in `activated`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a partially vectorised solution. Note [`pd.Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) is just a Python-level loop.

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'Time': list(range(1, 8)),
                     'Temperature': [25.6, 25.4, 24, 25.8, 23.2, 24.3, 28.1]})

activated = pd.DataFrame({'Time': [2, 4]})

def time_until_higher(x):
    current_temp = temp_s.at[x]
    diffs = temp_s[temp_s.index > x] - current_temp
    return (diffs < 0).values.argmin() + 1

temp_s = temp.set_index('Time')['Temperature']  # assume times are sorted
activated['Next'] = activated['Time'].apply(time_until_higher)

print(activated)

   Time  Next
0     2     2
1     4     3
```